# What are the binary strings of length 10 where the sum of the digits is $\leq 4$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I tought that for binary strings we mean a string made just by $0$s and $1$s, and the problem is to find all the possible strings whose sum of digits  is $\leq 4$.
But i don't know if considering the positional notation is required (because the problem is meaning that the sum must be $\leq 4$ in base 10), or it means that the base 2 addition between the digits must be equal to a binary string that in base 10 is equal to 4.

I would really appreciate a hint to have a better understanding of this.

p.s: This is my first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "sum of digits" in a binary string would just count the number of ones in that string. So for instance $1011110001$ has $6$ ones. You would not be interested in this string since it has more than four ones.  On the other hand you would be interested in the binary string $0110010010$.

Answer (score 0):

The number of such strings is $$\sum_{k=0}^4 \binom{10}{k} = \binom{10}{0} + \binom{10}{1} + \binom{10}{2} + \binom{10}{3} + \binom{10}{4} = 1 + 10 + 45 + 120 + 210 = 386.$$